# Improving my convoluted use of Gmail as a spam filter

Tags: email, google

My server hosts several email addresses, for both individuals and lists.  I do not provide SMTP or POP for these users... I simply forward each user's email to their "real" email address (or to a list of addresses) using the mail server's "aliases" file.

I am currently using Gmail as a spam filter in the following cumbersome way:  All users' mail is initially forwarded to a single Gmail account.  Using the Filter feature of Gmail, I forward it back to my server, but to a modified email address.  Finally I forward it to the real address.  It works because Gmail applies the spam filter **before** it applies the Filter feature.

So for users "joe" and "bob" my aliases file (on mysite.com) would have:

```
joe: myDummyEmail@gmail.com
joe-nospam: real.joe@aol.com
bob: myDummyEmail@gmail.com
bob-nospam: real.bob@yahoo.com
```

In myDummyEmail@gmail.com, I set up the filters:

```
To=joe@mysite.com forwards to joe-nospam@mysite.com
To=bob@mysite.com forwards to bob-nospam@mysite.com
```

This is basically working, except it's a pain to set up new users.  Also, I'm wondering if I could get better quality spam filtering by using the officially sanctioned method of pointing the MX record of mysite.com to gmail.com.  How could I duplicate my functionality by using the MX record in that way?  Any other ideas?

I'd prefer to not install an anti-spam solution on my own server, because in my experience, none are as good as gmail.

**EDIT:**

One complication with the MX / Google Apps solution is that for some email addresses I use the "pipe" feature of the aliases file to pipe the message through my own script. So I would want a way to forward some of the messages back to my server anyway.  And once I have pointed the MX record for myserver.com to Google, how can any messages be sent back to my server?

Comment: I don't even want to know what the SMTP headers look like on these messages.

Comment: You win my vote for "The Most Elaborate Workaround for Not Wanting to Set Up a SPAM Filtering System" award.

Answer (score 2):

No offense, but that's pretty messed up.

Just cut out all of the complications and move your domain(s) over to [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html). It's free (for up to 50 users/domain). You'll get sane management tools, great web interface, POP3/IMAP if your users want it, mobile push notification, etc.

Regarding your edit: I do this frequently, using `fetchmail` (run via cron) to retrieve messages via IMAP and then pipe them through a custom parser.

Comment: What if I want more than 50 and don't want to pay?

Comment: Plus, see my edit for an additional complication.

Comment: Well then pay up. Honestly, you get what you pay for. What happens when/if Gmail shuts down the account you're currently using. This *does* happen, especially if they catch wind of what is really an abuse of their system. You admitted that your current system is cumbersome and sub-optimal. If you need more than 50 accounts, you'll need to pay up. Even the paid version of GApps is a *steal* for the price.

Comment: Are you sure my current system is abuse?

Comment: From Google's TOS: "You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means". Sounds like abuse to me.

Comment: You are interpreting "sending email to a Gmail account" as "accessing a service through automated means"?

Comment: Honestly, whether this is abuse of Google's services or not doesn't really matter for this discussion. Your current situation is messed up - I think we all agree on that. You asked for alternatives. Since you're already familiar with Gmail, it seems like a move to GApps would 1) be quite simple and 2) fulfill all of your requirements.

Comment: +1 for the `fetchmail` idea

Comment: 5.5 Unless you have been specifically permitted to do so in a separate agreement with Google, you agree that you will not reproduce, duplicate, copy, sell, trade or resell the Services for any purpose.

Comment: @mattdm, good thing I am not doing any of those things, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @JoelFan: are those users not your customers? You can argue with me about it all you like; Google is eventually just going to cut you off, and you can try to explain the technicalities to them.

Answer (score 1):

A gmail/gapps account can forward all email delivered to it (after spam filtering) to another address (preferably forward and delete if you don't intend to check it). The account can also have at least a fair number of aliases on it. When a message is sent to an alias, gmail tags a "X-Remote-Delivered-To:" header containing that alias before delivering it to the account(s). With that combination, you should be able to have your server under a sub/different domain, use only one of the 50 accounts with many aliases pointing to it, and use procmail to deliver/pipe to a script as needed. In addition it'd all be push, with no polling of any gmail account needed.

Comment: I like that because it involves the least change to my current "system"!  Questions: (1) Are you sure the subdomain would work (e.g. myserver.com MX points to gmail.com, and nospam.myserver.com MXpoints to myserver.com)?  I am using GoDaddy for DNS (not hosting). (2) How do I get postfix to use the "X-Remove-Delivered-To" header instead of "To" for processing my own aliases file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GoDaddy's DNS config tool, but DNS itself would have no issue with that. You could test it first by adding some test subdomain and different MX records for it. As for postfix, I'm not familiar with its config options. I'd say pass the address off to procmail, and in procmail you'd just have a recipe with "* ^X-Remote-Delivered-To: address" and the destination address/file/command on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Google Apps solution as mentioned above, but instead of `fetchmail` I would recommend taking a look at [`offlineimap`](https://github.com/jgoerzen/offlineimap/wiki). It has some advanced capabilities like syncing directly between two IMAP servers, running pre and post hooks, etc. You might find this useful when migrating old email, as well.